# How to debug cannot access address using gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, arm, stack-trace

When I try to debug core file with gdb I dont see any valid stack trace to proceed further (similar to the reported issue in the link below). Can you please help me how I should debug further to debug the issue. Any pointers or gdb commands which will help in triaging the problem.

[GDB debugging trace with no relevant info (#0 0x2e6e6f69 in ?? ())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146819/gdb-debugging-trace-with-no-relevant-info-0-0x2e6e6f69-in)

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x76c0da28 in ?? ()
#1  0x76c0d9e0 in ?? ()
#2  0x76c0d9e0 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

EDIT: To rule out the possibility of the `-g` flag and `host environment` issues,I have intentionally added a code to crash and was able to get the correct stack trace from the corefile.

Comment: Did you compile the binary using `-g` option enabled?

Comment: yes it is compiled.

Comment: The corrupt stack message could indicate that something went wrong with your memory access ( most certainly invalid write ), other tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) could help figure out your issue.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to debug core file with gdb I dont see any valid stack trace

Was the core produced on the same host where it is being analyzed?

If not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629444/50617) explains what you need to do.

Comment: Yes it is on same host.